# Cannot find definition of "this.startup" in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement parse in a windows phone 8.1 application and I am using [this](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/windows_phone/existing) as my guide. In the code, this.Startup isn't recognized.

I am using a Windows phone 8.1 app and Not a silverlight app. So will parse notification work for only Silverlight apps and not Windows Phone 8.1 apps ?

I am providing the code below :

```
this.Startup += async (sender, args) =>
{
      // This optional line tracks statistics around app opens, including push effectiveness:
      ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);

      // By convention, the empty string is considered a "Broadcast" channel
      // Note that we had to add "async" to the definition to use the await keyword
      await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");
};
```

*Update*

```
namespace App2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        private TransitionCollection transitions;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
            //Parse code
            ParseClient.Initialize("yTu3sSPuBQe8A35fA1PEEXfqjHQJ84fFoDJlHy59", "vrldzsKd7jBgCP9x3z0vY43vpygvuzdYTTeR06wZ");

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used when the application is launched to open a specific file, to display
        /// search results, and so forth.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                // TODO: change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application
                rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
                if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
                {
                    this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                    foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                    {
                        this.transitions.Add(c);
                    }
                }

                rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
                rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
                }
            }

            await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");
            await ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpenedAsync(e);

            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

This is my current code.
Now how do I actually bind the Toast alert with the notification ?
I've done the same thing in android and there the Notification has been put in a service (Broadcast receiver). How do I get the same effect in Windows ? With a BackgroundTask ?If so, how to bind parse service in a background task ?

Comment: Does the command "await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");" properly work for you? I'm getting the following exception: "The notification platform is unable to connect to the cloud notification service."

Comment: I donot see that exception